# Hugo not generating the same styling as in development mode

Tags: html, css, themes, hugo, static-site

This is my first time I'm trying to generate a static website.

Everything works fine in development mode with `hugo server` command.
The styling is great, but when I'm trying to generate the final static files with `hugo` command the theme seems not to be applied properly and I don't understand why.

I've tried two themes (what's in the quickstart and another one) but I get similar results with both.

These are the commands what I've entered into console in the later case:

```
hugo new site testsite
cd testsite
cd themes
git clone https://github.com/cowboysmall-tools/hugo-devresume-theme.git
cd ..
cp themes/hugo-devresume-theme/exampleSite/config.toml .

hugo server
# styling seems to work

hugo
# the opened public/index.html is broken
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

I've followed these tutorials:

[quick-start](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/quick-start/)

[hugo-devresume-theme](https://themes.gohugo.io/hugo-devresume-theme/)

## UPDATE

after checking the errors in chrome console I can see values like this:

```
<link href="/dist/css/app.1cb140d8ba31d5b2f1114537dd04802a.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

if I delete the `/` from the beginning of `/dist/css/app.1cb140d8ba31d5b2f1114537dd04802a.css` the style seems to be applied correctly.

Obviously I don't want to do this every time manually. Is there any solution for this in configuration?

Answer (score 7):

Meanwhile I've figured out that the problem originates from this setting in `config.toml`:

```
baseURL = "mywebsite.com"
#...
```

Instead of the above setting I've tried this one and it seems to work now properly:

```
baseURL = ""
relativeURLs = "True"
#...
```

Comment: Setting `relativeURLs = "True"` is key. Especially if you added your own javascript/css files to the theme.

Comment: This works. Thanks man. You saved hours of my life.

Answer (score 0):

Once you set the `baseurl` in your theme config.toml there is no need to change it.

You probably figured out that `hugo` and `hugo server` are two different commands

- `hugo server` is for when you are developing your site and viewing it locally
- `hugo` you only run this when you are ready to deploy your finished site ... then copy all the files from the public/ folder to your website.

It's not intended for you to browse public/ folder from your local machine. Just use `hugo server`.

Answer (score 0):

Running `hugo` may not rewrite your `css` directory. If you want to ensure that it does, instead of running `hugo` in the command line, make a quick bash script that first deletes the `css` directory, and subsequently calls `hugo` to rewrite the files in that directory. Here is something I wrote which should work. I store this file in my `/scripts` directory.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
SCRIPTPATH="$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; pwd -P )"
cd "$SCRIPTPATH"/../docs/css/
rm home.min.css
rm page.min.css
cd "$SCRIPTPATH"/../
hugo
```

Then when I want to rebuild my `hugo` site, I run this script. I just call it `hugo.sh`.